# Defining TextView size to not overlap outer element

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout in a list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/poi_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/poi_image_descr" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/poi_image"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/poi_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/poi_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem here: the second `TextView` (whose id is `poi_description`) is overlapping the outer `CheckBox`. How can i modify this layout to have the `TextView`dynamically change its width and height to not to overlap the outer `CheckBox`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkbox"` to your `LinearLayout` to prevent any overlap